# Abort Trap 6 in a C++ program

Tags: c++

I wrote a mini game called "nqueens" that make use of array to represent a board of chess. I have wrote 5 functions for the game. However, every time when the game reach:

```
if (checkGameEnd(board, queenNumber) == 1) {
    if (checkResult(board) == 1) {
        cout << "Yeah! Problem Solved." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Oops! Not enough queens." << endl;
    }
    break;
}
```

in the main function, it shows ABORT TRAP (6). I search similar post in this forum, and most of the post said ABORT TRAP is related to accessing the memory that we don't own. But I have no idea which part of my code is accessing unowned memory. Can anyone find out the problem? Thanks so much.

To get into checkGameEnd == 1, type I 8, K 7, J 10, L 9, B 17, A 15 to the game.

full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
const int N = 18;

void printBoard(int [N][N], int);
int getAndProcessInput(int [N][N], int&, int&);
void flipBoard(int [N][N], int, int, int&);
int checkGameEnd(int [N][N], int);
int checkResult(int [N][N]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int board[N][N] = {0};
    int rowNumber, columnNumber, queenNumber = 0;

    while (1) {
        printBoard(board, queenNumber);
        if (checkGameEnd(board, queenNumber) == 1) {
            if (checkResult(board) == 1) {
                cout << "Yeah! Problem Solved." << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "Oops! Not enough queens." << endl;
            }
            break;
        }
        while (getAndProcessInput(board, rowNumber, columnNumber) != 0){
            cout << "Invalid. Try again!" << endl;
        }
        flipBoard(board, rowNumber, columnNumber, queenNumber);
    }
}

void printBoard(int board[N][N], int queenNumber) {
    cout << "   ";
    for (int i = 65; i < 65+N; i++) {
        char columnLetter = i;
        cout << columnLetter << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        cout << setw(2) << j << " ";
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            if (board[j][k] == 0) {
                cout << ". ";
            } else if (board[j][k] == 1) {
                cout << "= ";
            } else if (board[j][k] == 2) {
                cout << "Q ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "No. of Queens = " << queenNumber << endl;
}

int getAndProcessInput (int board[N][N], int& rowNumber, int& columnNumber) {
    char column;

    cout << "Make a move (col row): ";
    cin >> column >> rowNumber;

    if (column < 'A' || column > 'Z') {
        return 1;
    }

    columnNumber = (int)column - 65;

    if (columnNumber < 0 || columnNumber >= N) {
        return 1;
    } else if (rowNumber < 0 || rowNumber >= N) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (board[rowNumber][columnNumber] != 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void flipBoard(int board[N][N], int rowNumber, int columnNumber, int& queenNumber) {
    int a, b;

    board[rowNumber][columnNumber] = 2;

    //flip in north-east direction
    a = rowNumber - 1;
    b = columnNumber + 1;
    while (a >= 0 && b < N) {
        board[a][b] = 1;
        a--;
        b++;
    }


    //flip in east direction
    a = rowNumber;
    b = columnNumber + 1;
    while (b < N) {
        board[a][b] = 1;
        b++;
    }



    //flip in south-east direction
    a = rowNumber + 1;
    b = columnNumber + 1;
    while (a <= N && b < N) {
        board[a][b] = 1;
        a++;
        b++;
    }



    //flip in south direction
    a = rowNumber + 1;
    b = columnNumber;
    while (a < N) {
        board[a][b] = 1;
        a++;
    }   



    //flip in south-west direction
    a = rowNumber + 1;
    b = columnNumber - 1;
    while (a < N && b >= 0) {
        board[a][b] = 1;
        a++;
        b--;
    }



    //flip in south-west direction
    a = rowNumber;
    b = columnNumber - 1;
    while (b >= 0) {
        board[a][b] = 1;
        b--;
    }   



    //flip in north-west direction
    a = rowNumber -1 ;
    b = columnNumber - 1;
    while (a >= 0 && b >= 0) {
        board[a][b] = 1;
        a--;
        b--;
    }



    //flip in north-west direction
    a = rowNumber -1 ;
    b = columnNumber;
    while (a >= 0) {
        board[a][b] = 1;
        a--;
    }


    queenNumber++;
}

int checkGameEnd(int board[N][N], int queenNumber) {
    if (queenNumber == N) {
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int countEqual = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == 1) {
                countEqual++;
            }
        }
        if (countEqual == N) {
            return 1;
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}

int checkResult(int board[N][N]) {
    int checkQueenNumber[N] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == 2) {
                checkQueenNumber[j] = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }



    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        if (checkQueenNumber[k] != 1) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve your code to get no warnings. Use standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) in your code. **Use the debugger** `gdb`. Your *fix-my-code* question is off-topic.

Comment: BTW you could code with `constexpr int N = 10;`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am a newbie of coding and I know nothing to debug with GDB. I will learn how to use it to assist debugging by myself.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
    while (a <= N && b < N) {
//           ** <--- here
```

I have found it using the [address sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) of gcc. The usual suspects, gdb and valgrind, were of little use.

Asan and other gcc sanitizers are wonderful and underrated tools, you should learn to use them (together with gdb and valgrind of course).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this error. The code now works. I will follow your suggestions, to learn to use debugging tools to assist debugging. Thanks so much.